# i want to convert my number to text in dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm new in Dart and flutter.

I want to convert a number to text. How can implement this?

```
99 => Ninety-nine
100 => one hundred
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this package

install it

```
number_to_character: ^0.0.4
```

use it
just create an instance like this

```
var converter = NumberToCharacterConverter('en');
```

and set the language in the parameters

```
arabic => ar
frensh => fr
english => en
spanish => es
```

link of the package
https://pub.dev/packages/number_to_character